# Neo4j server connect while PC off?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm kinda new on neo4j 
I created a local database and wanted my teammates to connect to it remotely
so we downloaded Hamamchi VPN and connected to local network and all of them now can connect to the database using blot://localhost:port ,however the problem is that they can't connect to the server when my pc is sleeping since it's created on my PC.

is there another way to let them connect to my database even when my pc is on sleep mode?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. If the server isn't actively running on your machine then nothing can connect to it.

If you're just standing up a Neo4j server for a proof-of-concept or similar, then a sandbox instance on Neo4j's servers may do the trick. Check out https://sandbox.neo4j.com/